# Convert tabular file to an HTML table

Tags: shell

I need to print the following i/p in table format for mail using html tags in unix shell scripting.

i/p file : list.txt

```
a 2019 a 2020
b 2020 b 2001
c 2019 c 2013
```

i tried, but i got all the values in one column:

```
echo "<html>
        <head>
        <title>Table Load Status</title>
        <style>
        table, th, td {
                border: 1px solid blue;
                border-collapse: collapse;
        }
        th, td {
                padding: 5px;
        }
        </style>
        </head>
        <body>
        <table style='width:100%'>
                <tr bgcolor='#808080'>
                        <th>HEading 1</th>
                        <th>Heading2</th>
                        <th>Heading3</th>
                       <th>Heading4</th>         
                </tr>"
    for contents in  $(cat list.txt)
    do
            echo "<tr>
                    <td>$contents</td>
            <td>$contents</td>
                    <td>$contents</td>
             </tr>"
    done
```

current O/p:

```
 Heading1 heading2 heading3 heading4
     a      
    2019
    a
    2020
    b
    ....
```

desired O/p:

```
Heading1 heading2 heading3 heading4
 a       2019     a        2020
 b       2020     b        2001
 c       2019     c         2013
```

Please help. thanks in advance

Comment: Are you looking output in HTML format? Sorry but this is not clear. Could you please do edit your question with more details and let us know then.

Comment: yes html output format in tabular format

Comment: @Please post how the output should be looking in your question and let us know then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***EDIT:*** Adding 1 more solution which adds headings too in HTML output file, considering that very first line is heading if this is the case then try following.

```
awk -v s1="\"" '
BEGIN{
  print "<html>" ORS "<title>My title goes here...</title>" ORS "<head>"\
  ORS "<style>" ORS "table, th, td {" ORS "  border: 1px solid black;" ORS\
  "}" ORS "</style>" ORS "</head>" ORS "<body>" ORS "<table cellpadding=" s1 "10" s1 ">"
}
FNR==1{
  print "<tr>"
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
    print "<th>" $i "</th>"
  }
  print "</tr>"
}
{
  print "<tr>"
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
     print "<td>"$i"</td>"
  }
  print "</tr>"
}
END{
  print "</table>" ORS "</body>" ORS "</html>"
}'  Input_file
```

---

---

Could you please try following.

```
awk -v s1="\"" '
BEGIN{
  print "<html>" ORS "<title>My title goes here...</title>" ORS "<head>"\
  ORS "<style>" ORS "table, th, td {" ORS "  border: 1px solid black;" ORS\
  "}" ORS "</style>" ORS "</head>" ORS "<body>" ORS "<table cellpadding=" s1 "10" s1 ">"
}
{
  print "<tr>"
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
     print "<td>"$i"</td>"
  }
  print "</tr>"
}
END{
  print "</table>" ORS "</body>" ORS "</html>"
}'  Input_file
```

Above will generate following html file.

```
<html>
<title>My title goes here...</title>
<head>
<style>
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<table cellpadding="10">
<tr>
<td>a</td>
<td>2019</td>
<td>a</td>
<td>2020</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>b</td>
<td>2020</td>
<td>b</td>
<td>2001</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>c</td>
<td>2019</td>
<td>c</td>
<td>2013</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

When we open html file with browser then it will look like:

[image]

Comment: i tried but its not working at all.  print " <tr> " ORS "<th>" View Name OCE "</th>" ORS "</tr>"  
  Can you please provide the code for that too :)

Comment: @rose, Please check my EDIT answer and let me know then?

Comment: can you pls help me with https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/576926/find-difference-in-two-files?

Comment: is it possible to check if $==a then highlight only a ?